# Will it damage the battery if I use my MacBook Pro while playing WOW or just using it, while charging?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I just received my first MacBook Pro as a birthday gift, and I am one of those people that tends to "baby" their electronics. I also tend to play World of Warcraft (WOW) quite a bit, but the problem is that is drains the battery very quickly. I have a 13 inch Retina Display.

Comment: Why would it? The Laptop will probably feed off the socket anyway when it's plugged in, charging the battery will simply take longer.

Comment: Just enjoy it! If it flattens the battery too fast, use it plugged it in when you can. Worry about the battery life in a few years. [Cavalier attitude, I know, but otherwise you could worry for the same period of time, without extending the battery's life by more than a few weeks]

Comment: The more times you discharge/recharge the battery the less life it will have as that's just the way it works.  If you're doing something that is raptly draining the battery then do it with the AC adapter connected.

Comment: There could be a problem with the Charger. Open the About this Mac- More Info- Syst report -Power, and look for the Battery Voltage and Current and report here.

Comment: By the way, if you have access to an Apple store or a reputable reseller, I suggest actually *not* babying the machine.  Test it out with use cases you are likely to *need* it for, and if it's not doing what you want, take it back to the shop. Especially if it is software.  For the battery, just follow the instructions that come with the computer.  Also keep an eye on the battery status and pay attention to anything it says.  You get a certain amount of free service in the time just after you buy the machine, and as a new customer Apple will not want to risk you appering to be unsatisfied.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer says it's charging but the battery level percentage is still going down, then you're putting way too much stress on it. It's a rare occasion, but I have seen it happen once or twice.

If your battery percentage goes up, no matter how slowly, you should still be okay to use it while charging.

EDIT: Sorry, I don't know whether or not a charging-but-decreasing battery is actually bad for the hardware. I was just thinking that it's a situation that you should know could happen if you're doing a lot of battery-intensive processes. I don't know whether or not it damages your battery in the long run, just that it's possible that plugging your charger in won't actually charge the battery as quickly as you're draining it.

Comment: Do you have any reference for your claim ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Edited to say that no, I don't, my answer was thinking more in the short-term question of whether or not the battery can charge while playing WOW/being used. Should I delete my answer?